# .Net How to force a piece of code to be kept in designer.vb or designer.cs?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am working on a legacy .NET project that was converted from VB6. In VB6, there was the concept of Control array. After the conversion, the control array was converted to Microsoft.VisuaBasic.Compatibility.VB6.xxxArray.

For example, the following code was in Designer.VB.

```
Me._label_0 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
Me._label_1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
Me.label = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.LabelArray(Me.components)

Me.label.SetIndex(Me._label_0, CType(0, Short))
Me._label_0.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(29, 20)
Me._label_0.Name = "_label_0"
Me._label_0.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 20)
Me._label_0.TabIndex = 0
Me._label_0.Text = "label0"

Me.label.SetIndex(Me._label_1, CType(1, Short))
Me._label_1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(29, 53)
Me._label_1.Name = "_label_1"
Me._label_1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 20)
Me._label_1.TabIndex = 1
Me._label_1.Text = "label1"

Me.Controls.Add(_label_0)
Me.Controls.Add(_label_1)
```

Note that, there is `Me.label.SetIndex(Me._label_0, CType(0, Short))` to add _label_0 to the index 0 of the array.

The SetIndex is auto generated. That is to say, if I change anything in the Form Designer (the Designer.vb will be regenerated), this piece of code will still keep in designer.vb.

Now, because Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6 is deprecated. So I wrote a XXXArray (say MyLabelArray) myself. Everything works fine, except that the SetIndex part cannot be autogenerated.

That is to say, whenever I change anything in the Form Designer (say drag to change the position of the form or labels), the designer.vb will be regenerated, and all the SetIndex will be automatically removed.

Is there a way to force this small piece of codes to be kept in designer.vb?

Thanks.

Comment: LabelArray implements IExtenderProvider to add an "Index" property to Label controls.  Your replacement component needs to do that as well to keep it compatible and make SetIndex() work.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/d6c1xa43(v=vs.140)

Comment: Is it complicated to change the Array in a `List(Of Label)`? You could move that code to the Form's constructor (`Sub New()`, after `InitializeComponent()`). The collection can be accessed by index anyway and you can forget about the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

The answer is to implement the IExtenderProvider. The following is a simple example (not a completely functional objectArray as in VB6).

```
<ProvideProperty("Index", GetType(Label))>
Public Class MyLabelArray
    Inherits Components
    Implements IExtenderProvider

    Dim ctrDic As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Label)()

    Public Function CanExtend(extendee As Object) As Boolean Implements IExtenderProvider.CanExtend
        Return TypeOf extendee Is Label AndAlso ctrDic.Values.Contains(DirectCast(extendee, Label))
    End Function

    Public Sub SetIndex(ByVal ctr As Label, ByVal index As Integer)
        ctrDic(index) = c
        HookEvents(c)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetIndex(ByVal ctr As Label) As Integer
        For Each kvp In ctrDic
            If kvp.Value.Equals(ctr) Then
                Return kvp.Key
            End If
        Next
        Return -1
    End Function
End Class
```